# How to parse a MPD manifest video file and get segments of an image adaptation set?

Tags: xml-parsing, video-streaming, html5-video, video.js, mpeg-dash

I am using mpeg-dash mpd file to stream video using videoJS.

I am trying to display thumbnail of the video while using the seek bar.

The adaptation set for image is received on the manifest file. Now I am trying to parse the mpd file and get segments out of it. How can i achieve this using javascript?

I tried parsing the manifest file using https://www.npmjs.com/package/mpd-parser this plugin but this picks up only segments for Audio, video, subtitle and closed caption.

Is there a plugin which handles the same for image adaptation set?

Comment: An MPD file is just text. Did you open it in a text editor and see if there is any thing about thumbnails? Your  options are... **(1)** Use `String` functions to extract those image paths. Or else **(2)** Edit the source code of MPD Parser to handle the thumbnails..

Comment: Yes I could see a separate adaptation set for image(thumbnail). And also adaptation for video and audio. When parsed with the plugin mentioned above, I get segments(for each time interval for the entire video) for video and audio but not for image. I just want to get segments for image just like video and audio

Answer (score 0):

As I think you know, the images are in a separate adaptation set - from the DASH interoperability spec (https://dashif.org/docs/DASH-IF-IOP-v4.3.pdf):

> For providing easily accessible thumbnails with timing, Adaptation Sets with the new @con- tentType="image" may be used in the MPD. A typical use case is for enhancing a scrub bar with visual cues. The actual asset referred to is a rectangular tile of temporally equidistant thumb- nails combined into one jpeg or png image. A tile, therefore is very similar to a video segment from MPD timing point of view, but is typically much longer.

and

> It is typically expected that the DASH client is able to process such Adaptation Sets by download- ing the images and using browser-based processing to assign the thumbnails to the Media Presen- tation timeline.

It sounds like you want a tool or some code to allow you to be able to view the thumbnails - some players provide this at a user level, e.g. see TheoPlayer info here:

- https://www.theoplayer.com/blog/in-stream-thumbnail-support-dvr-dash-streams

You can also leverage and possibly reuse the parsing that is already built into an open source player - see this discussion in the Shaka Player support issues which provides the method to parse and retrieve thumbnails and also the thumbnail format itself:

- https://github.com/google/shaka-player/issues/3371#issuecomment-828819282

The above thread contains some example code to extract images also.